WinSCP меняет права на файл при редактировании файла
У меня возникла проблема с программой WinSCP. У меня есть файл (условно) a.php.
У этого файла установлены права 700 и владелец www-data:www-data.
При открытии файла и его редактировании через WinSCP после сохранения меняются права и владелец. Как отключить эту функцию, чтобы WinSCP не менял права и владельца файла?

Авторизоваться под пользователем которому  принадлежит файл?

https://superuser.com/q/1323408/213663

winscp не редактирует файл на месте. он скачивает его, открывает редактор, при сохранении закачивает обратно. так как под www-data залогиниться нельзя - приходится переустанавливать права каждый раз.
Лучшим решением для установки прав для вэб сервера я считаю наследование прав через acl
